# Limiting List Choices in JQuery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, html-lists

Other questions are posted similar to this, but my issue is simply that I don't know where to put the information. That said, I am trying to limit the number of items that are pulled from a list inside of the script below. The script itself works fine, I just need to limit the number of items pulled to six instead of everything. I feel like this is an easy one, but every line of code I inserted from other posts did't work for me. Any help?

```
(function($){
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/homepage_photo_slider/PhotoGallery.xml", 
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('img').each(function() {
                   var location = '/homepage_photo_slider/'; 
                   var url = $(this).attr('src');
                    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');

                    $('<li></li>').html('<a href="'+location+''+url+'" class="pirobox" rel="gallery" title="'+alt+'"><img class="thumb" src="'+location+''+url+'" alt="'+alt+'" title="'+alt+'" /></a>').appendTo('#gallery-ul');

             });
            $().piroBox_ext({
            piro_speed : 700,
            bg_alpha : 0.5,
            piro_scroll : true
    });  
            }       
        });     
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but I think this should work.  I only changed one line, which is marked in the comments.  I use the slice method to trim down the array to six elements before applying `each`:

```
(function($){
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/homepage_photo_slider/PhotoGallery.xml", 
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('img').slice(0,6).each(function() { // <--- CHANGED LINE HERE
                   var location = '/homepage_photo_slider/'; 
                   var url = $(this).attr('src');
                    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');

                    $('<li></li>').html('<a href="'+location+''+url+'" class="pirobox" rel="gallery" title="'+alt+'"><img class="thumb" src="'+location+''+url+'" alt="'+alt+'" title="'+alt+'" /></a>').appendTo('#gallery-ul');

             });
            $().piroBox_ext({
            piro_speed : 700,
            bg_alpha : 0.5,
            piro_scroll : true
    });  
            }       
        });     
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a for loop instead of your .each() method:

```
var $images = $(xml).find('img');
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    var $image = $($images[i])
    var location = '/homepage_photo_slider/'; 
    var url = $image.attr('src');
    var alt = $image.attr('alt');

    $('<li></li>').html('<a href="'+location+''+url+'" class="pirobox" rel="gallery" title="'+alt+'"><img class="thumb" src="'+location+''+url+'" alt="'+alt+'" title="'+alt+'" /></a>').appendTo('#gallery-ul');
}
```